# Isolate virtual environment dependecies from system-installed python on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, virtualenv, ubuntu-20.04

I'm on ubuntu 22.04 and installed pip using Linux package managers:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install python3-venv python3-pip
```

The point is that when I activate virtual environment and install dependencies on it:

```
source venv/bin/activate

pip install -r requirements.txt
```

, it installed on system-installed python rather than on a virtual environment.

```
which pip
```

output is: /usr/bin/pip which is the same folder without the virtual environment:

```
deactivate

which pip
```

the output is : /usr/bin/pip

the objective is to install the package only on the environment separately from system-installed python

Comment: It shouldn't have done that if you ran the commands properly. Did you do `source venv/bin/activate` first, then `pip install...`? The question makes it look like you did it all in one command. Did you use `sudo`? Without `sudo` you should not be able to install anything system-wide.

Comment: Please [edit] your question if you wish to add information. And please clearly separate each command so we can understand what you are doing.

Comment: Here are the steps:
1- sudo apt update 
2- sudo apt install python3-venv python3-pip
3- source venv/bin/activate
4- pip install -r requirements.txt
actually it's work i delete virtual environment  folder and redo the steps, and its works !! ( when i type which pip i got different path)
thanks

Comment: Again, please _edit your question_ to add more information

Comment: In such cases, I always recommend using `path/to/venv/python -m pip ...`: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: I remove the virtual environment folder and create a new one and now it works fine !!

Answer (score -1):

in directory of your project use this command to create virtual environment

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

if you wish to use other version of python first you should install it self and venv module with following command

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install python3.9 python3.9-venv python3.9-pip
```

to use venv first you need to activate it with:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

or

```
. venv/bin/activate
```

then use venv python with this command

```
pyhton3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Firstly i want use the version that i have on my system, and it seems like confusion on environment: so when i execute which python3 after activation & before, i got same path mean: /usr/bin/pythone